# .htaccess issue in Godaddy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have uploaded website on Godaddy server, but I am facing an issue with .Htaccess.

URLs are not redirecting through .htaccess

**Here is code**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?select=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?select=$1&a=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?select=$1&a=$2&b=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?select=$1&a=$2&b=$3&c=$4 [L]

    #RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([a-zA-Z\0-500000000\a-zA-Z\=_/|-][^/]*)/$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2&q=$3 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Server path for the folder/domain is:**

```
G:\PleskVhosts\pet-parents.com\sellf.ie
```

Comment: Do you get a 500 Internal Server error, or does it just not rewrite at all? Have you tried a simpler rewrite rule like just rewriting image.jpg to image.php?

Comment: @JamieBicknell i am getting this issue "404 - File or directory not found" you can check on this domain "sellf.ie"

Comment: And what about the second question?

Comment: No i didn't " as i have no idea about that @JamieBicknell

Comment: First advice would be to set up a basic rewrite only and see if that works, if it doesn't then there's an issue with HTACCESS as a whole, not with your rules.

Comment: i have uploaded thes files on another server and .htaccess is working properly.... this issue is only on this godaddy hosting

Comment: If it works elsewhere then the issue lies somewhere with the GoDaddy hosting configuration. Just noticed you have a path set like a Windows path, is your hosting running IIS or Apache?

Comment: @JamieBicknell its windows based.. how can i set .htacess for windows bases hosting?